# EasyOCR disables Cuda GPU when installed

Tags: opencv, gpu, anaconda3, easyocr

Hello after installing EasyOCR via pip install easyocr via Anaconda Prompt (base) I receive this error.

> OpenCV(4.5.4)
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/private.cuda.hpp:106: error: (-216:No CUDA support) The library is compiled without CUDA
> support in function 'throw_no_cuda'

Before installing easyocr, cuda is active and working with my GPU, but is disabled after installing EasyOCR.

I complied my build via Cmake using opencv4.5.4 and opencv-contrib4.5.4 with Cuda 11.3.1 and Cudnn 8.4.0 as well as uprading tot he most recent numpy 1.22.3.

It seems that after installing eascyOCR is changes my opencv build from whatever I am using to "opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.60" and that is I believe where the issues is at.

This is the version of easyocr installed.
Downloading opencv_python_headless-4.5.4.60-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (35.0 MB)
Successfully installed easyocr-1.4.2 opencv-python-headless-4.5.4.60 python-bidi-0.4.2

Any idea or help on how I can get easyocr working with Cuda and my GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

- Have to install `EasyOCR` first
- Then build `OPENCV`